# waitpid not working- efault error

Tags: c, fork, pid, waitpid

I am trying to make a fork that runs an exec in one file and then waits for it to be finished. If the exec in the child process is terminated by a signal I want to print the signal, if the program takes too long to run I want to print timeout.

```
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0) {
            //child process
        }
        else {
            alarm(timeout);
            int status;
            if(wait(pid, &status, 0) == pid) {
                alarm(0);
                fpw = fopen(testreport, "a+");
                if(WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
                    fprintf(fpw, "Run time errors: signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status);
                }
                else {
                    fprintf(fpw, "Run time errors: none");
                }
                fclose(fpw);
            }
            else {
                alarm(0);
                kill(pid, SIGTERM);
                fpw = fopen(testreport, "a+");
                fprintf(fpw, "Run time errors: timeout\n");
                fclose(fpw);
            }
        }
```

Testreport is a previously declared char * for a file name. The waitpid isn't working though. When I print the value of the waitpid and the errno resulting I get -1 and 14, respectively. I looked up errno 14 and it's an EFAULT, which would indicate that the address of status isn't valid. How can that be so?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. add -Wall to your gcc parameters.
2. More error check.
   In your codes fork() may return -1, and -1 is a valid input for waitpid, which may due to different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely this line:

```
        if(wait(pid, &status, 0) == pid) {
```

Here, you are calling `wait()` which takes only one parameter. It looks like you intended to call `waitpid()`, which takes three parameters (also, in your question title you are asking about `waitpid()`). If you call `wait()` with three parameters, then the results may be unpredictable and could certainly lead to the problems you observe.